# c# syntactic sugar overloading

Tags: c#, generics, operator-overloading

I have the following method:

```
virtual public int nonNeg(int? numIn)
    {
        if ((numIn < 0) || (numIn ==null))
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else return (int)numIn;

    }
```

I want to be able to have a single method which could take in either bytes, shorts, or ints to force these values to a nonnegative number.  How could I accomplish this?

Comment: Is performance an issue here or not?

Comment: I am confused by the question. Bytes are already non-negative, so why do you need to do anything to them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would not normally suggest this, but off the top of my head the following overloads should cover most your cases. They will cover the nullable types and the non-nullable types, the compiler will select the appropriate overload.

```
public static T nonNeg<T>(T n) where T : struct, IComparable
{
  if (n.CompareTo(default(T)) <= 0)
  {
    return default(T);
  }
  return n;
}

public static T nonNeg<T>(T? n) where T : struct, IComparable 
{
  if (!n.HasValue || n.Value.CompareTo(default(T)) <= 0)
  {
    return default(T);
  }
  return n.Value;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Or just use `Math.Max( 0, numIn)`

Comment: Maybe a GetValueOrDefault() in there?

Answer (score 2):

Possibly something like this (tested):

```
virtual public T nonNeg<T>(T numIn) where T : IComparable<T>
        {
            if (numIn==null){
                return default(T);
            }

            if (Comparer<T>.Default.Compare(numIn,default(T))<0)
            {
                return default(T);
            }
            else
                return (T)numIn;
        }
```

Comment: The problem here is casting back to an int for the comparison. You must add  "where T: struct" in order for the signature to be valid, and it is not so simple to convert any struct to an integer type. The simplest way really is to make overloads, or to use library functions as others suggest, or make the caller cast to int?.

Comment: This wont work. You cant use `<` against a generic parameter.

Comment: I encountered the same issue CMP suggested.  I would like to  see this above code modified and tested to make the code more elegant in my project, since using the Math.Max does not handle nullable types

Comment: **1)** constrain the method to be `where T : struct`. **2)** Compare using `( Comparer<T>.Default.Compare ( numIn.Value, default ( T ) ) < 0 )` and **3)** return default(T) instead of 0.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this with:

```
int negativeNumber = -22;
int nonNegativeNumber = Math.Abs(negativeNumber);
```

result will be 22

OR

```
decimal negativeNumber = -22.2;
decimal nonNegativeNumber = Math.Abs(negativeNumber);
```

result will be 22.2

Comment: Nope, I don't want the absolute value.